# SAS Import XLS file without headings

Tags: sas

I am importing an XLS file with dataset looking like this:
[image]

And my code was as below:

```
    %let dirLSB=/folders/myfolders/sasuser.v94/;
    proc import datafile="&dirLSB.OnionRing.xls" out=sales replace;
run;
proc print data=sales label;
run;
```

But the result showed the first row had been treated as headings and the 
row data for the first row "Columbia Peaches" was missing.
It should have been four rows but in the end, only three rows were present.

Are there any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `getnames=no;` statement to your `proc import` step.

```
proc import datafile="&dirLSB.OnionRing.xls" out=sales replace;
  getnames=no;
run;
```